# spring-data-mongodb using the fieldName instead of _id

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a Pojo with an attribute as

```
    Class A{ 
        @Id
        @Field("item_id")
        private String itemId;
    }
```

When i try to update a document in MongoDB collection based on the itemId as below, it worked well and able to see from mongo ops logs that the query was transformed as "_id in itemIds "

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("itemId").in(itemIds));
Update update = new Update();
update.set("field2", "abd");
mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, A.class)
```

When i upgraded to spring-data-mongodb-2.1.5.RELEASE, the query i saw in the mongo logs  was "item_id in itemIds". Since item_id is not a field and no index for that field in the collection, the query took forever to complete.

Any help to understand why the spring-data library is building the query as _id in older version and using the field as it is in newer version?

Answer (score 1):

After a 2 minute search on the Spring documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html/mapping-chapter.html):

> The following outlines what field will be mapped to the '_id' document field:
>
> - A field annotated with @Id (org.springframework.data.annotation.Id) will be mapped to the '_id' field.
> - A field without an annotation but named id will be mapped to the '_id' field.

Did you try that already?

Comment: Yes, we are using @Id already. Also the doc says https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongo-template.id-handling

Comment: you are indeed using `@Id` but also `@Field` which is intended to override the name of the column. So, please try to remove the `@Field` annotation and keep only the `@Id` one

Comment: I get the same issue, not using `@Field`. Writing to db transforms to "_id" but findById uses the field name and queries by "id".